# Get value from ChoiceField and returns filtered result

Tags: python, django

How do I get the value from a ChoiceField dropdown list and returns a list of filtered result back to frontend?

Currently I can only show the values in the dropdown list but I failed to return back the selected result

Update: now I managed to show it using Class based views but I still not able to show the filtered result in the same page

#### views.py

```py
class Index(FormView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
    form_class = IndexForm


    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        rest_list = Restaurant.objects.order_by('-restname')

        query_results = Restaurant.objects.all()
        region_list = regionChoiceField()

        context['rest_list'] = rest_list
        context['query_results'] = query_results
        context['region_list'] = region_list
        context['form'] = IndexForm()
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            region_list = request.POST.get('region_list')
            print("region_list - ", region_list) 
# Where can I check the print out result? There is no return value in python console

            return redirect(reverse('food_review:index')) 
# want to return the list in the same page
```

#### index.html

```html
<body>
    <form method="post" name="dropdown">{% csrf_token %}
            {{ region_list }}
    </form>

    <table>
        {% for rest in query_results %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ rest.restname }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
</body>
```

#### forms.py

```py
from .models import *
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.forms import Widget

class regionChoiceField(forms.Form):
    region = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Restaurant.objects.values_list("region",flat=True).distinct(),empty_label=None)

class IndexForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # self.error_class = ErrorListMsg

    region_list = forms.ChoiceField(choices= [(r.id, r.region) for r in Restaurant.objects.all()], required=False,
        widget=forms.Select())
#key: restaurant id, value: region of restaurant

    def clean(self):
        form_data = self.cleaned_data
```

#### models.py

```py
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    restname = models.CharField(max_length=200)  # Field name made lowercase.
    phone = models.IntegerField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cuisine = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    region = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_modify_date = models.DateTimeField()
    created = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.restname
```

#### urls.py

```py
app_name = 'food_review'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', Index.as_view(), name='index'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a class based view instead of function based and importing form mixin.

**views.py**

```
class Index(FormView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
    form_class = IndexForm


    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        rest_list = Restaurant.objects.order_by('-restname')

        query_results = Restaurant.objects.all()
        region_list = regionChoiceField()

        context['rest_list'] = rest_list
        context['query_results'] = query_results
        context['region_list'] = region_list
        context['form'] = IndexForm()
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            region_list = request.POST.get('region_list')
            print("region_list - ", region_list)

            return redirect(reverse('NextClassViewYouWantToRedirect'))
```

**models.py** (same as yours)

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    restname = models.CharField(max_length=200)  # Field name made lowercase.
    phone = models.IntegerField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cuisine = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    region = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_modify_date = models.DateTimeField()
    created = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.restname
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import Widget

class IndexForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # self.error_class = ErrorListMsg

    region_list = forms.ChoiceField(choices= AnyChoiceTupleYouWantToBeDisplayed, required=False,
        widget=forms.Select())

    def clean(self):
        form_data = self.cleaned_data
```

**index.html** (same as yours)

```
<body>
    <form method="post" name="dropdown">{% csrf_token %}
            {{ region_list }}
    </form>

    <table>
        {% for rest in query_results %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ rest.restname }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
</body>
```

Also, you would require to add the same in your urls.py file (I'm assuming you would have done this already)

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', index.as_view(), name='index'),
]
```

Let me know if it works.
Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, please see my updated code. Now i can display the dropdown list in class based views but still unable to return filtered result back to frontend.....

Comment: Can you explain where do you want the filtered(selected) value? Is it in the same page or the different page? You can fetch the selected value using the post method which I had mentioned
`
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            region_list = request.POST.get('region_list')
            print("region_list - ", region_list)
`
and then you can pass it to your next template using context